# Magento 2 delete event get product skus using observer

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, event-observer, adminhtml, bulk-actions

I need to perform a operation when a product is deleted from admin. So I have created a observer using below code which is working fine.

Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_delete_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ProductDeleteAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\Observer\ProductDeleteAfter.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductDeleteAfter implements ObserverInterface
{    
   /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * customer register event handler
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct(); 
        $_sku=$_product->getSku();        
        die(var_dump($_sku));
    } 
}
```

Here I am getting only last selected product even though when I selected multiple products using checkbox. I want all the selected products Id or sku.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your observer function's code :

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $_sku = $_product->getSku();
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/Rohan.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($_sku);
        return $this;
    }
```

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: thanks for you support but it's not working.. I'm getting the sale result.

Comment: It's because, you stop execution using die.

Comment: Check my updated answer and update your code. Check log file. You will get multiple skus.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great it's working great. can I get this as array?

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :) No, it's call on every product delete action. So, it will return one by one.

Comment: Thanks I got what I need. You saved my day